# Disable hyperlink after single click

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

i have classic ASP form ,in that there is a hyperlink as follows.
        `<A href="javascript:ProcessForm()" >go here</A>`

ProcessForm() submits the form to another page if validation is true.

```
function ProcessForm() {
    if (validateform() == true) {
    document.form1.action = "abc.asp";
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

How can i disable the hyper link after a single click if validation is true?  tried adding an id for the hyperlink and disabling it , then the text gets greyed out but on clicking the greyed text the page gets submitted multiple times. also tried with return false onclick.
Please suggest .

Comment: After the process call have you tried removing the link instead of disabling it? `$('#link_id').attr('href', '');`

Answer (score 0):

Set a global flag:

```
var hasSubmittedForm = false;
```

And then check that flag:

```
function ProcessForm() {
    if (hasSubmittedForm) return false;
    else hasSubmittedForm = true;

    if (validateform() == true) {
        document.form1.action = "abc.asp";
        document.form1.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply. tried this.But it will work only when validation is true ,also in case of multiple click even though it creates only 1 record, it shows a page with only "false" on it. When validation fails , it disables the link and user cannot click it again . Here the page abc.asp in case of successful processing calls the page xyz.asp. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick event to your link:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <a href="" onclick="ProcessForm(this);">go here</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript>
    function validateform() {
        return true;
    }

    function ProcessForm(link) {
        if (validateform() == true) {
            link.removeAttribute('href');
            document.form1.action = 'abc.asp';
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @SoftCrearR:Thanks for the reply. This code is not making the form submit.it just stays there.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it with jQuery like this:

Here you go:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#RemoveLink").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(url);
    $("#RemoveLink").removeAttr("href");
    });
});
</script>

<a href="http://www.google.bg/" id="RemoveLink">go here</a>
```

Tested and working, tell me if this is not the functionality you want or mark my answer as answer for your question ;)

Comment: @Tonny Struck:Thanks for the reply. But here ahref is calling a js function and not opening a new page ,can you please include the code to handle when validation fails , it should allow user to click again.